# Randomly sample a group within a group

Tags: r, group-by, sample

I need to sample a location from a date for each unique id and I don't want to sample with replacement. My hang up is I also don't want the dates to repeat

```
    df<-data.frame(id<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
date=c(2020-01-01,2020-01-01,2020-01-01,2020-01-02,2020-01-02,2020-01-02, 2020-01-02,2020-01-02,2020-01-03,2020-01-03,2020-01-04,2020-01-03-4,2020-01-04,2020-01-05,2020-01-06,2020-01-06,2020-01-07,2020-01-07), 
location<-c("xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy","xy"))

    view(df)
```

This is the closest I've been able to get

```
df2<-df %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  sample_n(1, replace = F) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  sample_n(1,replace = F)
```

But on a larger data set this fails to sample all the available IDs I need to sample from (particularly the ones with a smaller range of days. I feel like there should be a for loop out there I need, I just haven't been able to come up with it myself.

Comment: there is sample_frac and the new slice_sample

Comment: also your reprex fails, and this 2020-01-03-4 does not look like a date

Comment: Are you sure there's a solution? What if you have 3 IDs that only occur on the same 2 days? Theoretically this is a pretty complicated problem even if there is a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I'd think that quick heuristics for doing this could be prone to distributional bias in your sampling, so perhaps you just go all-out stochastic. There is technically no guarantee that this will get you what you need (depending on your data) within a reasonable time. Or at all.

You have two constraints:

- *"sample a location from a date for each unique id"*; and
- *"don't want the dates to repeat"*.

I'm assume that there are more dates than ids ... otherwise this would be a futile effort.

Let's keep the first constraint (`id`) as gospel, and iterate until the second is resolved:

```r
### just for this answer ... do not do this in production
set.seed(42) # R-3.5.3

iter <- 100 # prevent a near-infinite loop
FOUND <- FALSE
while (!FOUND && iter > 0) {
  samp <- do.call(rbind, by(df, df$id, function(z) z[sample(nrow(z), 1),]))
  ### dplyr analog
  # samp <- group_by(df, id) %>% sample_n(1) %>% ungroup()
  FOUND <- length(unique(samp$date)) == nrow(samp)
  iter <- iter - 1L
}
FOUND
# [1] TRUE
iter
# [1] 98

samp
#   id       date location
# 1  1 2020-01-02       xy
# 2  2 2020-01-03       xy
# 3  3 2020-01-04       xy
# 4  4 2020-01-06       xy
```

This will suffer with larger datasets, obviously, but should eventually find an acceptable sampling if it theoretically exists.